# Qt: Downloading a file doesn't work

Tags: file, qt, ssl, download

For three days now I try to come up with a workable code to simply download a file from an Url, but I had my fair share of problems so far and now I am at a point where I can't see the error.

First of all, my code:

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    w.downloadArchive(QString("https://bitbucket.org/BattleClinic/evemon/downloads/EVEMon-binaries-1.8.1.4016.zip"), QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath(), QString("evemon.zip"));

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QFile>
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkReply>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    bool downloadArchive(QString archiveUrl, QString saveToPath, QString archiveName);

private slots:
    void downloadReadyRead();
    void downloadProgress(qint64 bytesReceived, qint64 bytesTotal);
    void downloadFinished();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QMessageBox>

QNetworkAccessManager manager;
QFile *file;
QNetworkReply *reply;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->downloadLabel->hide();
    ui->downloadProgressBar->hide();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::downloadReadyRead()
{
    if(file)
    {
        file->write(reply->readAll());
    }
}

void MainWindow::downloadProgress(qint64 bytesReceived, qint64 bytesTotal)
{
    ui->downloadProgressBar->setMaximum(bytesTotal);
    ui->downloadProgressBar->setValue(bytesReceived);
}

void MainWindow::downloadFinished()
{
    downloadReadyRead();
    file->flush();
    file->close();

    if(reply->error())
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this, "Download failed", tr("Failed: %1").arg(reply->errorString()));
    }

    reply->deleteLater();
    reply = NULL;
    delete file;
    file = NULL;

    ui->downloadLabel->hide();
    ui->downloadProgressBar->hide();
}

bool MainWindow::downloadArchive(QString archiveUrl, QString saveToPath, QString archiveName)
{
    QUrl url(archiveUrl);

    if(archiveName.count() <= 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(QFile::exists(saveToPath + "/" + archiveName))
    {
        QFile::remove(saveToPath + "/" + archiveName);
    }

    file = new QFile(saveToPath + "/" + archiveName);

    if(!file->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
    {
        delete file;
        file = NULL;
        return false;
    }

    reply = manager.get(QNetworkRequest(url));

    connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(downloadFinished()));
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(downloadReadyRead()));
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)), this, SLOT(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)));

    ui->downloadLabel->setText(QString("Downloading %1...").arg(archiveName));
    ui->downloadLabel->show();
    ui->downloadProgressBar->show();

    return true;
}
```

Downloader.pro

```
QT       += core gui network

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Downloader
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

In mainwindow.cpp I'm checking for an error and print it to a MessageBox, in case there is one. The first error I had with the current code in the reply was "Unable to init SSL Context", because I'm requesting data from a https-site. I googled a while and found the solution to be two files called "libeay32.dll" and "ssleay32.dll" I had to copy to the executable's directory.

There are now no more errors within the reply (at least the MessageBox doesn't show up)....however, after the downloadFinished Function was executed, the downloaded file has a size of 0 kb, which makes me think, their wasn't at all a download happening.

I skipped the "if(reply->error())" statement and showed the MessageBox no matter what....I got an: "Unknown Error". Should an "Unknown Error" not set the "if(reply->error())" statement to true?

There is no problem with permissions either....I tried it as Admin....so no problem at creating the file itself.
Can anyone help me to get that code working?
Do I miss any dlls or an #include?

Thanks

Comment: Is the `downloadReadyRead` slot ever called?

Comment: Yes. It is called and the file is valid. The write should be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that it works for a non-ssl file.  Then to add ssl support, try following the directions in the answers to this question:

[Qt SSL support missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516143/qt-ssl-support-missing)

Also try using `qDebug` in your code instead of the QMessageBox most of the time.  It makes adding debugging lines easier, and it won't interrupt your code or fill your screen with QMessageBoxes.

Comment: The download from a http-site is working. Will check your link and report back.

Comment: I installed the latest openssl. "QSslSocket::supportsSsl()" returns true. However, it doesn't work yet. Also tried to add "CONFIG += openssl" to the.pro file. Didn't work either.

Comment: Did you try running `configure.exe -debug-and-release -webkit -openssl -I C:\openssl\Include -L C:\openssl\Lib`?

Comment: Here is an example that should work: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-http-httpwindow-cpp.html ... And if Qt is really working for ssl correctly, then `QT_NO_OPENSSL` should be undefined.

Comment: So that should mean that QT_OPENSSL is working.  Are you able to run that HTTP Window example?  It may be included in your SDK.

Comment: I am able to run that example and it is working like a charm. The index file is downloaded correctly.

Comment: Where you able to verify that it was using SSL (accessing the https server) in that example, using a debug statement or a messagebox?

Comment: Well, it wrote the https url automatically in the LineEdit, so i thought it would use it. Will check that.

Comment: Yes, it is using SSL. Thanks. :-D

Answer (score 2):

Download with SSL:

```
connect(&http, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(finishedHttp(QNetworkReply*)));
QNetworkRequest *req = new QNetworkRequest();
req->setUrl( QUrl("https://...") );
QSslConfiguration configSsl = QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration();
configSsl.setProtocol(QSsl::AnyProtocol);
req->setSslConfiguration(configSsl);
http.get(*req);
```

You need: libeay32.dll, libssl32.dll, ssleay32.dll (from OpenSSL) and Visual c++ 2008 SP1 redist package.