# Qt Application crashes whenever WebKit tries to load HTML

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtwebkit, qsslsocket

I'm using Qt 4.7.4 with C++ and I'm trying to embed a html document with some flash elements into a Qt application. To start out I added a QWebView widget to my main window and tried to load a html document stored on my harddrive, that caused an error so I looked up the Qt examples and attempted to run the youtube viewer example here: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Embed_YouTube_Video_in_QWebView

Both times I got the same issue when attempting to run the program:

```
"The procedure entry point ??1QSslSocket@@UAE@XY could not be located 
in the dynamic link library QtWebkit4.dll"
```

I used dependency walker and it states that QSslSocket is in QNetwork4.dll which is in my release folder (and it's the release version). Also my QTDIR environment variable points to the correct location and the location of the bin folder is in my path variable.

So I was wondering if anyone here could help me out. I'm also using visual studio 2005 (unfortunately using Qt 4.7.4 and vs 2005 are out of my control in this instance)

Comment: Qt must've been compiled with SSL support turned on. Also try to download and install the the latest OpenSSL binaries.

Comment: Is that a default because I used nmake in the visual studio command prompt to compile QT. I'll give it a try and report back

Comment: You're comment lead me to google "Qt built without SSL" that turned me onto this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516143/qt-ssl-support-missing . The install hasn't finished but I'm confident this is solved :D

Comment: @user1646196: did it work out?

Comment: Not quite, when I rebuilt QT with SSL installed it failed (possibly because it was the latest SSL with heartbleed patched), so I installed Qt5.2 which worked instantly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to check the following things:

- Your Qt installation is built with SSL support.
- You have the SSL dll correctly recognized.
- You have the version required to avoid symbol mismatches.