# Static QT build with SSL support using Windows + MinGW?

Tags: c++, qt, openssl, mingw, qt-creator

I'm trying to compile my Qt based application using static linking. So after few days of struggling I have found [this article](http://qt-project.org/wiki/How-to-build-a-static-Qt-for-Windows-MinGW) about compiling Qt libraries as static environment.

Everything was OK until I reached problem with SSL support. So I have figured out that in [this script](https://sourceforge.net/p/qtlmovie/code/ci/master/tree/build/windows-build-qt-static.ps1?format=raw) (referenced from mentioned article) is configuration which uses **-no-openssl** parameter. But the build is failing when I try to use different option (`-openssl` or `-openssl-linked`).

I suppose I have to compile OpenSSL itself. Is it possible to do that just using MinGW bundled with Qt Creator ?

If not, how can I then `link` my static Qt environment with compiled OpenSSL in order to successfully build my Qt project through Qt Creator ?

Comment: a related topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516143/qt-ssl-support-missing

Comment: I have OpenSSL installed, so when I use dynamic linking everything works just fine.